# make a condition in gnuplot when the valeur of column is a string

Tags: plot, statistics, gnuplot, static-analysis

I have this file data.dat in gnuplot
and i want to plot a graph that shows me the percentage of failures in the system according to 'hardware' and 'software' per year.
here is te data (minimal):

```
 ticket_id  time_down   time_up minutes_down    category    type    description    
        23350   01/15/06 07:24 PM   01/16/06 02:19 PM   1135    "HARDWARE"  "UNSCHEDULED"   " NGF - HARDWARE - UNSCHEDULED - TLFSSV05 DOWN"
        23351   01/16/06 01:21 AM   01/16/06 01:34 AM   13.3    "HARDWARE"  "UNSCHEDULED"   " NGF - HARDWARE - UNSCHEDULED - TLFSSV06 DOWN"
        23353   01/16/06 04:18 AM   01/16/06 04:49 AM   31  "HARDWARE"  "UNSCHEDULED"   " NGF - HARDWARE - UNSCHEDULED - TLFSSV01 DOWN"
        23355   01/16/06 04:20 AM   01/16/06 05:54 AM   94  "SOFTWARE"  "UNSCHEDULED"   " NGF - SOFTWARE - UNSCHEDULED - TLFSSV09 - HOST DOWN"
        23356   01/16/06 04:21 AM   01/16/06 04:59 AM   38  "SOFTWARE"  "UNSCHEDULED"   " NGF - SOFTWARE - UNSCHEDULED - TLFSSV13 - HOST DOWN"
        23357   01/16/06 04:23 AM   01/16/06 04:59 AM   36  "SOFTWARE"  "UNSCHEDULED"   " NGF - SOFTWARE - UNSCHEDULED - TLFSSV02 - HOST DOWN"
```

i tried this to first sort falures by "hardware" :

```
plot 'hope.dat' u  ($3-$2):4:($5=='"HARDWARE"') w histogram
```

but i get this error :Non-numeric string found where a numeric expression was expected

Answer (score 2):

- In order to check for a string you must use `stringcolumn(5)` instead of `$5` (a shortcut for `column(5)`, which gives the numerical value of the column).
- string comparison is done with `eq`.
- When plotting `with histogram`, gnuplot itself uses integer x-positions. Probably you want to use `with boxes`.
- You cannot just use normal subtraction for two different time data.
- Since you have white spaces inside the time values, your column counting is wrong.
- Gnuplot cannot handle `am` and `pm` in the input.

Comment: so i must change the column with time and date value . and i get this now : 
gnuplot> plot 'data.dat' u stringcolumn(5)=='"HARDWARE"'    
                                            ^
         stringcolumn() called from invalid contex

Comment: I'm new at this , and i have only less than an hour to send this , trying all day to sort this graph .. please if you have any idea .

Comment: To start from scratch: What kind of plot do you want to have? What's the x-value, what the y-value etc?

Comment: xrange =years
yrange=percentage
each year with scheduled and unscheduled with category =software

Comment: i'll change the years to only (2001,2002...)