# Gnuplot histogram : coloring only particular bars based on data column

Tags: gnuplot, histogram

I have been reading about coloring only certain histogram bars based on a property in a column in a data file. I need a boost in this area. Let's take a look at test code :

[1] data file:

```
1  4     3 this
2  7    21 this
3 11    43 that
4  5     6 this
5  2    51 that
```

[2] gnuplot code :

```
reset ;
set title "testing color of certain histogram bars \n \
based on property in data file (column 4)"
set bars back ;
set style data histogram ;
set style histogram cluster;
set style fill solid border -1 ;
set grid back ;
set grid xtics ytics mytics mxtics ;
set style line 2 lt 1 lc rgb "black" ;
plot newhistogram "", \
'test_08oct22a.dat' u 2:xticlabels(1) t 1, \
'' u 3:xticlabels(1) t 2
```

[ back to the question ]

I am stuck, having done unproductive work on this. I'd like to have gnuplot read the data file and, e.g., use "that" to color that bar green. "this" would be left alone. So if column 4 entry is "that", color the bar green. So bars (3, 43) and (5, 51) would be green, while all other bars use the initial color scheme. It helps to see the graphics here.

Here is what I tried:

I am focused on the part with e.g. xticlabels(1). I have found a couple ways to approach this - on the Stack Exchange or Stack Overflow sites -  but do not understand them. one way was a conditional based on numerical value. Unfortunately, I seem to have lost the URL for this. One article that I found that is somewhat helpful is https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-create-conditional-plotting-with-gnuplot/ :

```
u (column(0)):2:(0.5):($3=>1?1:2):xtic(1) w boxes lc variable
```

the inequality was working to some extent, but I do not understand how it is working in the rest of the code. I was confused by the use of xtic, lines, boxes, and such - the mytics and mxtics are being used as part of the larger script, so I kept them in to see if they are part of this problem.

Another approach that looked interesting was string matching, which I found a couple posts on :

[Conditional plot according to a string value in gnuplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66588265/conditional-plot-according-to-a-string-value-in-gnuplot)
and
[make a condition in gnuplot when the valeur of column is a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28054295/make-a-condition-in-gnuplot-when-the-valeur-of-column-is-a-string)

... so I am stuck - appreciate any pointers. The string matching would be preferable, if that helps.

some specs :

```
gnuplot 5.4 patchlevel 2
Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS jammy
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What is the actual condition to make a bar red or green? Is it just column 4 with the colorname written in the file or does it actually depend somehow on columns 2 and 3? For example, if column3 >40 then green.

Comment: The colors all over the place were confusing, I thought, so I changed the data file and question to be "this" or "that" property. I am going for a string, not a numerical value. "apple" and "orange" would work too. It sure would be cool to compute the value, but my real objective is to calculate whether a number is composite or prime. So I'll settle for a string - "composite" or "prime". However, part of what I tried is to put a 0 or 1 in column 4, and then evaluate that digit - as the code I found can do - I just couldn't get it to color the bar as I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I would say there is no need to for style histogram, it's a simple bar chart (check `help with boxes`).
You define a function `myColor()` which uses the ternary operator (check `help ternary`). If column 4 is equal to `"that"` return `0x00ff00` (=green) and `0xff0000` (=red) otherwise. You need to use `strcol()` and string comparison `eq`.
There is no need for `xtic()` if column1 is the linenumber.

**Script:**

```
### conditional color for boxes
reset session

$Data <<EOD
1    4     3   this
2    7    21   this
3   11    43   that
4    5     6   this
5    2    51   that
EOD

set boxwidth 0.3
set style fill solid 0.5
set xrange[0.5:5.5]
set key top left noautotitle
set grid y

myColor(col) = strcol(col) eq "that" ? 0x00ff00 : 0xff0000

plot $Data u ($1-0.2):2              w boxes lc rgb "red", \
        '' u ($1+0.2):3:(myColor(4)) w boxes lc rgb var
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Wow - this changes things - I need to work that out but in the meantime, should this let e.g. the box for 43 and 51 be colored "that"? This is part of my confusion, I could not see 'til now. BTW much thanks to all, I see how well Stack Overflow works.

Comment: @Bryan-MathStackExchange so, question answered or do you now want to color the boxes in the color "that" from the datafile (i.e. red/green as it was in your initial question)?

Comment: I want to color only the box for column 3 a special color if it is type "that". The chart above would have the 6th and 10th boxes from the left... green.

Comment: @Bryan-MathStackExchange ok, so then column2 is always red? No condition on column2? See edited answer.

Comment: Exactly - I understand now.